# construct \externaldocument command's argument for programmable cross referencing

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, expansion

My ver12.tex and ver12_SM.tex documents cross reference each other using the xr package. How could I program them such that when going over to ver13 the two \externaldocument commands do their job without manually hard coding the current file names into them.

The lines below produce compilation error:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[M-]{\StrBefore*{\jobname}{_SM}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one way round you can use

```
\externaldocument{\jobname_SM}
```

and in the other you can use

```
{
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\S=12
\catcode`\M=12
\gdef\stripsm#1_SM{#1}
}

\externaldocument{\expandafter\stripsm\jobname}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the pattern of the name of the two files is
`⟨common part of the two filenames⟩.tex` and
`⟨common part of the two filenames⟩_SM.tex` ?

A problem with the macros of the *xstring*-package is that they are not expandable.
This means they do not just deliver tokens that get processed/expanded in LaTeX's gullet and after expansion yield sequences of character-tokens. They also deliver non-expandable tokens for performing temporary assignments (`\def` and the like) which get carried out in LaTeX's stomach. Such unexpandable non-character-tokens cannot be parts of filenames. In the stomach the sequence of character-tokens that forms the filename should already be there, not interspersed with other non-expandable tokens, because further processing of the filename also takes place in the stomach.
Therefore with the macros of the *xstring*-package you need to use their optional arguments for defining macros that expand to the result of the operation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{xstring}

%======================================================================%
% This will check whether the token-sequence that forms the expansion  %
% of \jobname ends with "_SM".                                         %
% If so, \JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase will be defined to expand to    %
% the result of removing the last occurrence of "_SM" from the         % 
% expansion of \jobname.                                               %
% If not so, \JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase will be defined to expand   %
% to the result of appending the phrase "_SM" to the expansion of      %
% \jobname.                                                            %
\newcommand\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase{}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\SMPhrase{_SM}%
\@onelevel@sanitize\SMPhrase
\IfEndWith{\jobname}{\SMPhrase}{%
  \StrCount{\jobname}{\SMPhrase}[\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase]%
  \StrBefore[\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase]{\jobname}{\SMPhrase}[\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase]%
}{%
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter            \def
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter            \JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase
  \expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter            {%
  \expandafter\jobname
  \SMPhrase}%
}%
\global\let\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase=\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase
\endgroup
%======================================================================%

\message{^^J\string\jobname\space expands to:^^J\jobname}
\message{^^JPress return to proceed.}
\immediate\read-1 to\MyScratchmacro

\message{^^JMeaning of \string\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase\space is:^^J\meaning\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase}
\message{^^JPress return to proceed.}
\immediate\read-1 to\MyScratchmacro

\externaldocument[M-]{\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase}
\begin{document}

Bla Bla

\end{document}
```

Instead of using *xstring* you can use delimited arguments for having LaTeX detect whether the token-sequence that forms the expansion of `\jobname` ends with the sequence `_SM` and if so define the control-word-token `\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase` to expand to the expansion of `\jobname` with the phrase `_SM` removed, and if not so define the control-word-token `\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase` to expand to the expansion of `\jobname` with the phrase `_SM` appended.

An issue you might face is that `\jobname` delivers a sequence of character-tokens of category-code 12(other) (exception: spaces will have category-code 10(space)) while tokenizing the phrase `_SM` from .tex-input-file usually yields an underscore (`_`) of category-code 8(subscript) trailed by `S` and `M` both of category-code 11(letter). So with sequences of character-tokens tokenized from .tex-input you might need to apply `\@onelevel@sanitize` for transforming all these characters into their pendants of category-code-12(other). (As to the exception with the spaces: `\@onelevel@sanitize` transforms space-character-tokens into space-character-tokens of category-code 10(space).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}

%======================================================================%
% This will check whether the token-sequence that forms the expansion  %
% of \jobname ends with "_SM".                                         %
% If so, \JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase will be defined to expand to    %
% the result of removing the last occurrence of "_SM" from the         % 
% expansion of \jobname.                                               %
% If not so, \JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase will be defined to expand   %
% to the result of appending the phrase "_SM" to the expansion of      %
% \jobname.                                                            %
% For detecting the end, advantage is taken of the fact that the       %
% expansion of \jobname cannot contain any control-sequence-token      %
% and therefore cannot contain the control-word-token \relax.          %
% The empty-test via \if\relax<stuff>\relax..\else..\fi also takes     %
% advantage of this fact and of the fact that \if triggers expansion   %
% until finding two non-expandable tokens whose character-codes can be %
% compared, while for control-word-tokens like \relax a character-code %
% outside the range of character-codes possible for character-tokens   %
% is assumed.                                                          %
\newcommand\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase{}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\SMPhrase{_SM}%
\@onelevel@sanitize\SMPhrase
\expandafter\def\expandafter\GobbleToSMPhraseNRelax
\expandafter#\expandafter1\SMPhrase\relax{}%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\RemoveSMPhraseNRelax
\expandafter#\expandafter1\SMPhrase\relax{#1}%
\edef\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase{%
  \if\relax\expandafter\expandafter
           \expandafter           \GobbleToSMPhraseNRelax
           \expandafter\jobname
           \expandafter\relax
           \SMPhrase\relax\relax
    \jobname\SMPhrase
  \else
    \expandafter\RemoveSMPhraseNRelax\jobname\relax
  \fi
}%
\global\let\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase=\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase
\endgroup
%======================================================================%

\message{^^J\string\jobname\space expands to:^^J\jobname}
\message{^^JPress return to proceed.}
\immediate\read-1 to\MyScratchmacro

\message{^^JMeaning of \string\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase\space is:^^J\meaning\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase}
\message{^^JPress return to proceed.}
\immediate\read-1 to\MyScratchmacro

\externaldocument[M-]{\JobNameWithOrWithoutSMPhrase}
\begin{document}

Bla Bla

\end{document}
```

By the way:

You can test the examples above by saving as `test.tex` and running latex on the shell.

If you run latex without the `-jobname`-option, i.e., `latex test.tex`, then `\jobname` will expand to `test` (all characters of category-code 12(other)) and `\meaning\test` will display: `macro:->test_SM`

If you run latex with the `-jobname`-option for providing a trailing `_SM`, i.e., `latex -jobname=test_SM test.tex`, then `\jobname` will expand to `test_SM` (all characters of category-code 12(other)) and `\meaning\test` will display: `macro:->test`